# How I can fix this error? Pascal

Tags: loops, compiler-errors, pascal, goto

```
PROGRAM RandomNumber;
Var rand,count,guess : integer;
LABEL correct, loop, wrong, end1;
begin
{Initialization, so that random numbers are drawn}
 Randomize;
  count :=0;
  repeat
      loop:
      count := count+1;
{Random(i) Creates random numbers between 0 and i.}
      rand := Random(10);
      guess := Random(10);
      if rand=guess
      then
          goto correct
      else
          goto wrong;
  until count > 10;
  goto end1;
  correct :
      WriteLn('Correct');
      goto end1;
  wrong :
      WriteLn('False Guess');
      goto loop;
  end1 :
      WriteLn;
end.
```

The goal of the program is to find a random number in 10 tries. I managed to compile it with Free Pascal IDE and the problem then is that the program does not stop until the number is found. However, when I tried to compile it with an online compile it gives this error:

prog.pas: In main program:

prog.pas:26: error: `goto' to invalid target

Is it because labels/goto can`t jump right away in loops?

Comment: Ugh! Get rid of `goto` before it ever gets into your code. If you feel the need to write a `goto` you're doing something wrong. You can do what you need without writing a single `goto` statement with a simple `while` loop and counter variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proximate "why does't it work?!" answer is [exactly as lamas shaikh says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26958676/240490): A missing semicolon.

Don't feel bad. It's an easy thing to miss. Pascal allows either a single line of code after after a conditional or loop structure, or a `begin`/`end` sequence as a virtual statement. That choice interacts badly with Pascal's use of semicolons as statement *separators* rather than *terminators* (a fine distinction to parser designers but one that over the years has proven subtle and error-prone, especially for those new to the language. **Beware both missing and extra semicolons!**

Two things that can help: Always, always, **always** use strong, consistent, disciplined indentation to help show you the logical structure of the code. And you may find it easier to just always use `begin`/`end` blocks in any context that either a statement or a multi-statement block might fit (even if the block contains contains a single line). That may seem goofy at first, but as you start adding statements to programs (including temporary debugging print statements), working with a single construct that works in all cases really helps.

The less immediate reason that your program fails isn't the semicolon. It's that you're using a **completely** unstructured approach to control flow in your program. You're `GOTO`ing all over the place, even when you don't need to, and even though there are simpler, cleaner, better structured alternatives. For example, consider:

```
PROGRAM RandomNumber;
Var rand, count, guess, MaxGuesses : integer;

begin
    {Initialization, so that random numbers are drawn}
    Randomize;
    MaxGuesses := 10;
    count := 0;
    repeat
        count := count + 1;
        {Random(i) Creates random numbers between 0 and i.}
        rand  := Random(10);
        guess := Random(10);
        if rand = guess
        then begin
            WriteLn('Correct');
            break
        end
        else
            WriteLn('False Guess');
    until count >= MaxGuesses;
    WriteLn;
    if (rand = guess)
    then
        WriteLn('We had a winner (', guess, ') in ', count, ' tries.')
    else
        WriteLn('Sorry! No winner in ', MaxGuesses, ' tries.');
    WriteLn;
end.
```

Compiled and run a few times, it looks like:

```
$ ./guess
False Guess
Correct

We had a winner (1) in 2 tries.

$ ./guess
False Guess
False Guess
False Guess
False Guess
False Guess
False Guess
False Guess
False Guess
False Guess
False Guess

Sorry! No winner in 10 tries.

$ ./guess
False Guess
Correct

We had a winner (8) in 2 tries.
```

Pascal was part and parcel of the revolution in programming in the 1960s and 1970s that brought "structured programming" into widespread use. Don't use lower-level `goto`-laden code when better structures are so eagerly available.

Comment: Why people put up with the Dangling else problem has baffled generations, and basically there is only inertia as explanation. I don't consider Pascal's solution any worse than other languages' solutions, like e.g. C's associate with nearest IF. The smart thing is to not have it at all (e.g. like Pascal cousin Modula2 did, removing the one statement exception, and earn back some of the pain that causes by omiting the block opener (begin, { whatever)

Comment: Pascal's more verbose block keywords make it *slighly* worse than C's braces. But yes, "don't do that!" is the real fix. Or as a stopgap, always use a block. Languages like Python, Ruby, and Modula-2 that simply assume a block of statements follow get it right.

Comment: The first comment is a matter of taste, and that is definitely not my taste, I think the more verbose keywords in Wirthian languages give more visual feedback, and despite lore, mere typing is rarely limiting). Stopgap solutions that are not compiler enforced doesn't really fix the problem IMHO. Still syntax (and minimalism) is not everything in the real world, so that is why I don't use Modula2 anymore :-)

Answer (score 1):

You are missing semicolon after goto statement given below:

```
    goto correct
else
    goto wrong
```

Comment: It might be a little misleading. Give it a go with semicolon.

Comment: nope, the second semicolon is okay, but in the first gives error:

 
   `prog.pas:17: error: syntax error before `else'`

Comment: Can you update your question with semicolon. Am sure something wrong with updated code.